# Angular: conditional filter?

Tags: angularjs

I am displaying data from a large json object and want to filter the value as a currency, but only if it exists. Otherwise I want to print out a dash.  The problem I am having is that the currency filter will filter the dash into nothing.  Is there a way to filter on the first part of a conditional but not the second?

**Want to show either the dollar amount or a dash**

```
{{obj.dollarAmount || '-'}}
```

**Also want to filter the dollar amount as a currency (this obviously is invalid code)**

```
{{obj.dollarAmount | currency || '-'}}
```

**This is not what I want because it will display an empty string when it should be showing a dash. (because currency filter on a dash returns an empty string)**

```
{{obj.dollarAmount || '-' | currency}}
```

Comment: maybe make a custom filter, sounds like something you're going to reuse.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a ternary statement against the dollar amount like so:

```
{{obj.dollarAmount ? (obj.dollarAmount | currency) : '-'}}
```

The alternative would be to create a custom filter that looks at the amount and either applies the currency filter or returns `-`.

**Edit**

As @ergonaut mentioned, it is probably best to go with a filter for reusability. If you wanted to go that route:

```
.filter('myCurrency', [
  '$filter',

  function($filter) {
    return function(amount) {
      return amount ? $filter('currency')(amount) : '-';
    };
  }
]);
```

This is very similar to the ternary statement (and uses the same `currency` filter) with extra benefits. First it is reusable, you can use `{{obj.dollarAmount | myCurrency}}` anywhere in your application. You can also add additional validation against the `amount` or modify the display of the amount.

Answer (score 1):

You were very close.  Evaluate the value as currency first, and then apply the conditional.

```
{{(obj.dollarAmount | currency) || "-"}}
```